# SQL Server Database Diagram

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssms, database-diagrams

I am using SSMS v18, I need to create an ER diagram from my database. As Microsoft removed diagram from new version of SSMS (v18) so now How can I get a diagram for my database??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database diagrams have been re-added as of [18.1 in SSMS](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/06/11/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-1-is-now-generally-available/).